# Create a DataFrame with data from a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a DataFrame to which I want to import data from a class. I mean, I type `t1 = Transaction("20221128", "C1", 14)` and I want a DataFrame to show data like:

1. Column 1: Date
2. Column 2: Concept
3. Column 3: Amount

The code where I want to implement this is:

```
class Transactions:

    num_of_transactions = 0
    amount = 0

    def __init__(self, date, concept, amount):
        self.date = date
        self.concept = concept
        self.amount = amount
        Transaction.add_transaction()
        Transaction.add_money(self)

    @classmethod
    def number_of_transactions(cls):
        return cls.num_of_transactions

    @classmethod
    def add_transaction(cls):
        cls.num_of_transactions += 1

    @classmethod
    def amount_of_money(cls):
        return cls.amount

    @classmethod
    def add_money(cls, self):
        cls.amount += self.amount

t1 = Transaction("20221128", "C1", 14)
t2 = Transaction("20221129", "C2", 30)
t3 = Transaction("20221130", "3", 14)
```

I tried:

```
def DataFrame(self):
    df = pd.DataFrame(self.date self.concept, self.amount)
```

But looking at pandas documentation, I have seen it is not a valid way.

Any help on that? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In order to create a new data frame, you have to provide the rows and the columns name.

You have to change the code as the following:

```
def DataFrame(self):
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[self.date, self.concept, self.amount]], columns=['Date','Concept','Amount'])
```

Answer (score 1):

for the example you provided we can do some modifications in the class so we could get a dataframe easily:

```
class Transaction:

    num_of_transactions = 0
    amount = 0
    transactions = []  # <----- class atribute added

    def __init__(self, date, concept, amount):
        self.date = date
        self.concept = concept
        self.amount = amount
        Transaction.add_transaction()
        Transaction.add_money(self)
        Transaction.transactions.append(self)  # <----- append added
```

now we can get a dataframe like this:

```
pd.DataFrame([t.__dict__ for t in Transaction.transactions])

>>>
'''
       date concept  amount
0  20221128      C1      14
1  20221129      C2      30
2  20221130       3      14
```